# Dedicated rayon pool to submit work and asynchronously wait for completion

Tags: rust, async-await, rayon

I have a `rayon::ThreadPool` which I want to use to perform CPU bound tasks outside of Tokio's runtime context. The CPU bound tasks are synchronous tasks.

The problem is `spawn` requires the closure to be `'static` but I want to use the borrowed data instead of making owned copies.

Initially I thought `scope` would work (and the code compiles too), but it seems that it will block until the closure completes - which will defeat my purpose of using this pool i.e. to not block the tokio runtime.

How can I achieve this with rayon or any other threadpool implementation?

```rust
pub struct TaskPool {
    pool: ThreadPool,
}

impl TaskPool {
    pub fn new(num_threads: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            pool: ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
                .num_threads(num_threads)
                .build()
                .unwrap(),
        }
    }

    pub async fn verify(&self, hash: &[u8], data: &[u8]) -> bool {
        let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
        self.pool.spawn(|| {
            let ok = hash == calc_sha1(data);
            tx.send(ok).unwrap();
        });
        rx.await.unwrap()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be7a7f77374129a9ae4b01871795282f)

Comment: I'm not sure that would be sound. What's to stop someone to start awaiting `verify()` with owned data, and then drop the future after `calc_sha1()` commences, but before it finishes? There is good reason why scope-based interfaces block.

Comment: If you control the data type and insist on not making a copy, you could use `Arc`. Or more awkwardly, you could move the data into the closure and return it after the operation through the channel.

Comment: @user4815162342 - I agree on the soundness issue. I generally see use cases where you have an async task that you want to run from sync context - so you make an executor and call `block_on` and wait for it to finish. My use case is opposite, I have sync work from async context that I want to run in a separate thread pool and *not* block but rather asynchronously wait for it to finish.

Comment: @piojo - The awkward approach seemed too awkward. I ended up with `Arc` (for now).

Comment: Awaiting sync from async is not uncommon at all, e.g. virtually all filesystem operations work like that, as so does interfacing to CPU-bound or "legacy" non-async blocking code. Since it requires the use of threads, the standard approach is to learn to live with the `'static` requirement and pass around owned data, if necessary faking it with `Arc`. This is not always possible, as your `verify()` example shows - there is no way to use an `Arc` to pass data to `calc_sha1()` without modifying the signature of `verify()` or copying `data`.